# How to solve a fatal error detected by java runtime environment

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, java-8, fatal-error

I have been facing some problem with my android studio. When I going to run my android application into the emulator. It create a log file and shows a fatal error has been detected by java runtime environment.

Bellow is my error details :

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9bdf29b717, pid=1808, tid=0x00007f9bb90d4700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5e2717]  PhaseCFG::schedule_pinned_nodes(VectorSet&)+0xc7
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f9bd80fa800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1820, stack(0x00007f9bb8fd4000,0x00007f9bb90d5000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 128 (SI_KERNEL), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000000007f, RBX=0x00017f9b9083dbc0, RCX=0x00000000fffdffdf, RDX=0x00007f9b9d337660
RSP=0x00007f9bb90d07c0, RBP=0x00007f9bb90d0820, RSI=0x0000000000000001, RDI=0x00007f9b9ce4de50
R8 =0x00007f9b9ce4de50, R9 =0x00000000000001a3, R10=0x00007f9b9d337640, R11=0x00007f9bdef31db0
R12=0x00007f9bb90d08a0, R13=0x00007f9b9ce4dd30, R14=0x00000000ffffffff, R15=0x00007f9bb90d20a0
RIP=0x00007f9bdf29b717, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010212, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f9bb90d07c0)
0x00007f9bb90d07c0:   00007f9bb90d0820 00007f9bb90d07d0
0x00007f9bb90d07d0:   000016730000007f 0000000000000000
0x00007f9bb90d07e0:   00007f9b00000007 00007f9b9d337660
0x00007f9bb90d07f0:   00007f9b358637bd 00007f9bd80faf00
0x00007f9bb90d0800:   00007f9bb90d08a0 00007f9bb90d20a0
0x00007f9bb90d0810:   00007f9bb90d20f8 00007f9bd80faf00
0x00007f9bb90d0820:   00007f9bb90d0910 00007f9bdf29ec2f
0x00007f9bb90d0830:   00007f9b00000040 00007f9b9c659010
0x00007f9bb90d0840:   00007f9b9c659820 00007f9b9c660ff8
0x00007f9bb90d0850:   000000000011df28 00007f9b90d9fb80
0x00007f9bb90d0860:   00007f9b90d89a88 0000000000000002
0x00007f9bb90d0870:   00007f9bb90d08c0 00007f9bb90d08c0
0x00007f9bb90d0880:   00007f9bb90d0910 00007f9bdf29c7b0
0x00007f9bb90d0890:   00007f9bb90d0910 00007f9bb90d20a0
0x00007f9bb90d08a0:   00007f9bdfc23cf0 00007f9bd80faf00
0x00007f9bb90d08b0:   0000000000000100 00007f9b6340b470
0x00007f9bb90d08c0:   00007f9b00000080 00007f9bd80faf00
0x00007f9bb90d08d0:   00007f9b902cfb00 0000000000000000
0x00007f9bb90d08e0:   00007f9bb90d0940 00007f9bb90d20a0
0x00007f9bb90d08f0:   00007f9bb90d15d0 00007f9bb90d0940
0x00007f9bb90d0900:   00007f9bb90d20a0 00007f9bdfc41760
0x00007f9bb90d0910:   00007f9bb90d0930 00007f9bdf29f18a
0x00007f9bb90d0920:   00007f9bb90d20a0 00007f9bb90d2e00
0x00007f9bb90d0930:   00007f9bb90d2160 00007f9bdf15bd5d
0x00007f9bb90d0940:   00007f9bdfc1b1f0 0000000000000006
0x00007f9bb90d0950:   00007f9bb90d2e00 00007f9bd80faf00
0x00007f9bb90d0960:   00007f9bd80faf00 0000000000002000
0x00007f9bb90d0970:   00007f9b9c0dddd0 0000000000000000
0x00007f9bb90d0980:   00007f9bd80faf00 0000000000002000
0x00007f9bb90d0990:   00007f9b9c45d630 0000000000000000
0x00007f9bb90d09a0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f9bb90d09b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f9bdf29b717)
0x00007f9bdf29b6f7:   b0 48 8b 45 c8 4c 89 2c d0 8b 45 b0 85 c0 74 47
0x00007f9bdf29b707:   48 8b 55 c8 83 e8 01 89 45 b0 48 98 48 8b 1c c2
0x00007f9bdf29b717:   8b 4b 28 89 c8 c1 e8 05 41 3b 44 24 10 73 4a 89
0x00007f9bdf29b727:   c0 83 e1 1f be 01 00 00 00 48 c1 e0 02 49 03 44
```

I am using Linux mint os. Now i want to resolve this problem. Can Someone suggest me what to do? By the way i am using updated jdk.